# Input to unicode in mysql and angular

Tags: mysql, angularjs, unicode

Let's say i have an input where i ask the user to put just the letter of a card.
Let's say "KdKc".
Beside of showing the user a KDKC/kdkc/KdKc i would like to show the unicode for the suits. K⋄K♣

Anyone knows how do i do this conversion?

I am inserting it into table like this:

```
$hand = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
        $hand_names = array('handNumber', 'hand');
        $keys = array_keys($hand);
        $columns = '';
        $values = '';
        foreach($column_names as $desired_key){ // Check the hand received. If blank insert blank into the array.
           if(!in_array($desired_key, $keys)) {
                $$desired_key = '';
            }else{
                $$desired_key = $hand[$desired_key];
            }
            $columns = $columns.$desired_key.',';
            $values = $values."'".$$desired_key."',";
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO hands_table(".trim($columns,',').") VALUES(".trim($values,',').")";
        if(!empty($hand)){
            $r = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);
            $success = array('status' => "Success", "msg" => "Hand Created Successfully.", "data" => $hand);
            $this->response($this->json($success),200);
        }else
            $this->response('',204);    //"No Content" status
```

and showing through a ng-repeat

```
 <tr ng-repeat="data in customers">
            <td>{{data.hand}}</td>
            <td><a href="#/edit-hand/{{data.handNumber}}" class="btn">&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>&nbsp; Edit Hand</a></td>
        </tr>
```

I appreciate the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a filter? Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UBeDldQuTnZRmQq7NRzd?p=preview)

```
app.filter('cardSymbol', function() {
  return function(input) {
    if (!input) {
      return input;
    }
    input = input.replace(/s/g, '\u2660');
    input = input.replace(/h/g, '\u2665');
    input = input.replace(/d/g, '\u2666');
    input = input.replace(/c/g, '\u2663');
    return input;
  }
});
```